# Tree built with Twitter Bootstrap and Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, tree, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a simple modular tree built with Twitter Bootstrap  and Backbone.js that provides common tree control functionality?

Comment: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/05/composite-views-tree-structures-tables-and-more/

Comment: Were we able to solve your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a Bootstrap tree widget (from "[Trees in Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167628/trees-in-twitter-bootstrap/16823729#16823729)"):

Building on [Vitaliy's CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15480307/1430996) and [Mehmet's jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16664260/1430996), I  changed the `a` tags to `span` tags and incorporated some [Glyphicons](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons) and [badging](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges) into [my take on a Bootstrap tree widget](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/).

**Example:**
[image: my take on a Bootstrap tree widget]

For extra credit, I've created a [GitHub project to host the jQuery and LESS code that goes into adding this tree component](https://github.com/jhfrench/bootstrap-tree) to Bootstrap. Please see the project documentation at http://jhfrench.github.io/bootstrap-tree/docs/example.html.

Alternately, here is the LESS source to generate that CSS (the JS can be picked up from the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/)):

```
@import "../../../external/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less"; /* substitute your path to the bootstrap.less file */
@import "../../../external/bootstrap/less/responsive.less"; /* optional; substitute your path to the responsive.less file */

/* collapsable tree */
.tree {
    .border-radius(@baseBorderRadius);
    .box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05));
    background-color: lighten(@grayLighter, 5%);
    border: 1px solid @grayLight;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 19px;
    a {
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 90%;
    }
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px 0;
        padding: 4px 0px 0px 2px;
        position: relative;
        &::before, &::after {
            content: '';
            left: -20px;
            position: absolute;
            right: auto;
        }
        &::before {
            border-left: 1px solid @grayLight;
            bottom: 50px;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            width: 1px;
        }
        &::after {
            border-top: 1px solid @grayLight;
            height: 20px;
            top: 13px;
            width: 23px;
        }
        span {
            -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid @grayLight;
            border-radius: 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 14px;
            padding: 2px 4px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        &.parent_li > span {
            cursor: pointer;
            /*Time for some hover effects*/
            &:hover, &:hover+ul li span {
                background: @grayLighter;
                border: 1px solid @gray;
                color: #000;
            }
        }
        /*Remove connectors after last child*/
        &:last-child::before {
            height: 30px;
        }
    }
    /*Remove connectors before root*/
    > ul > li::before, > ul > li::after {
        border: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently published my backbone.js tree widget.Check it out at https://bitbucket.org/dnation/bbtree/ and see if it meets your needs.