# Typeahead Select List Supporting Tree Structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to create a select list control that supports data with a tree structure and has typeahead capability.

The data looks like this:

```
Category
    -> SubCategory
Category2
    -> SubCategory
        -> SubSubCategory
Category3
Category4
```

I would like the full parent->child structure to be displayed in the dropdown when the typeahead targets the SubSubCategory.

The closest I've come is using chosen: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

This supports one level of nesting, but because `<optgroup>` tags are not nestable in html that's as many levels as you can go.

Is there an alternative library that supports this, or how would you patch chosen to support this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a tree control of sorts. There are various ones around the web for jQueryUI and Twitter Bootstrap.

For example, here's [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167628/trees-in-twitter-bootstrap) with several JSFiddles and GitHub repos implementing tree controls.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I can get answers like these from google. "Is there an alternative library that supports this, or how would you patch chosen to support this?"

Comment: Sorry, you asked, "Is there an alternative library that supports this?" and I pointed you to some extensions of jQuery UI and Bootstrap. If this isn't what you're looking for, can you clarify your question?

Comment: I'm trying to create a select list control that supports data with a tree structure and has typeahead capability.

Comment: OK, you won't be able to do that with the <select> control. You'll need to implement a custom one, or use a custom one someone else has built. In the answer, I linked to a StackOverflow thread containing several options, from jQueryUI tree, to a Bootstrap tree, to a pure CSS tree. Do those help?