# How should I go about creating a lazy-loading tree through Spring MVC?

Tags: jquery, spring, plugins, tree, lazy-evaluation

I have a Spring MVC application that gets its data from Hibernate.  I'm trying to create a tree that upon clicking a node, loads data from the controller and displays the appropriate children.  I'm having trouble figuring out what Jquery tree plugin to use and how to pass json data to it using the controller.

can someone recommend a jquery tree plugin that is very easy to use and has helpful examples/tutorials?  I can find a million jquery plugins that say they do lazy loading but there are so few tutorials/examples for each that I have no idea how to implement this in my application.  Really appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you need to see this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167628/trees-in-twitter-bootstrap). Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

[jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) is good. It supports JSON data sources and AJAX loading. Some information about lazy loading: http://www.miketyka.com/2012/10/lazy-loading-with-jstree-and-ajax/

Comment: ...so my problem is that none of these plugins have very extensive documentation or examples.  I understand how all of these work, but I don't understand how to send and retrieve json data and I seriously can't find a single tutorial that explains all of it.